# GnuPG: Updated gpg setpref for 2024

Tags: gnupg, default-settings, public-key-encryption

Using Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS with GnuPG 2.2.27 and libgcrypt 1.9.4.
Would someone in the know please suggest what the gpg --edit-key, setpref input should look like for 2024? Or a current gpg.conf file? All the suggestions I can find are a few years old.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Found it! Tails v. 5.21 has the following gpg.conf file by default.

```
#
# This is an implementation of the Riseup OpenPGP Best Practices
# https://riseup.net/en/security/message-security/openpgp/best-practices
# Source: Tails v. 5.21, December 24, 2023


#-----------------------------
# default key
#-----------------------------

# The default key to sign with. If this option is not used, the default key is
# the first key found in the secret keyring

#default-key 0xD8692123C4065DEA5E0F3AB5249B39D24F25E3B6


#-----------------------------
# behavior
#-----------------------------

# Disable inclusion of the version string in ASCII armored output
no-emit-version

# Disable comment string in clear text signatures and ASCII armored messages
no-comments

# Display long key IDs
keyid-format 0xlong

# List all keys (or the specified ones) along with their fingerprints
with-fingerprint

# Display the calculated validity of user IDs during key listings
list-options show-uid-validity
verify-options show-uid-validity

# Try to use the GnuPG-Agent. With this option, GnuPG first tries to connect to
# the agent before it asks for a passphrase.
use-agent


#-----------------------------
# keyserver
#-----------------------------

# When searching for a key with --search-keys, include keys that are marked on
# the keyserver as revoked
keyserver-options include-revoked


#-----------------------------
# algorithm and ciphers
#-----------------------------

# list of personal digest preferences. When multiple digests are supported by
# all recipients, choose the strongest one
personal-cipher-preferences AES256 AES192 AES CAST5

# list of personal digest preferences. When multiple ciphers are supported by
# all recipients, choose the strongest one
personal-digest-preferences SHA512 SHA384 SHA256 SHA224

# message digest algorithm used when signing a key
cert-digest-algo SHA512

# This preference list is used for new keys and becomes the default for
# "setpref" in the edit menu
default-preference-list SHA512 SHA384 SHA256 SHA224 AES256 AES192 AES CAST5 ZLIB BZIP2 ZIP Uncompressed
```